# Hide "Unread" menu option in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook 2013 how do I hide the "Unread" menu link at the top of my email list?

[image]

I find I accidentally have select this and miss my old emails.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to click "All" and that should show all of your emails. Be sure to check what folder you have selected on the left pane and make sure the Inbox or another folder with messages is selected.

*Edit*
I'm sorry I misread your statement as being you currently couldn't see them, not that it is an annoyance. As far as I can tell its hard coded as an option.

Comment: As per the question: how do I hide the link?